# Making interface for these two PHP classes?

Tags: php, class, interface

Ok, I need a little help. I have these two PHP classes

```
class menu
{
    public static function GetItems ()
    {
        $res=array();
        $r=mysql_query("select * from menuitems");
        while($rw=mysql_fetch_row($r))
        $res[]=new MenuItem($rw[0],$rw[1],$rw[2],$rw[3]);
        return $res;
    }
}
```

And second

```
class Articles
{
    public static function Get ()
    {
        $res=array();
        $r=mysql_query("select * from articles");
        while($rw=mysql_fetch_row($r))
            $res[]=new Articles($rw[0],$rw[1],$rw[2],$rw[3]);
        return $res;
    }
}
```

I need a simple PHP interface class that can write all this inside, just to change MENUITEMS, and articles. Basically I need something like this as an interface

```
interface Base
{
    $res=array();
    $r=mysql_query("select * from $base");
    while($rw=mysql_fetch_row($r))
        $res[]=new $base($rw[0],$rw[1],$rw[2],$rw[3]);
    return $res;
}
}
```

And in the other class I need something that I can calllike this

```
 class menu
 {
    public static function GetItems ()
    {
        $baza="Articles";
    }
}
```

You know what I mean, my class `Menu` needs to implements class `baza`, and there was `$baza`, just replace with this string?

Ok, lots of says can not do that in interface, i agree, but i need solution, for my question?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense at all. None of it. An interface is just a collection of function prototypes. You cannot put any programming logic in there. Your menu::GetItems() at the end does nothing at all.

Comment: you can do this with a common base class and static member variables (and some tricks if you have an old php)

Comment: you mean "how can I call $avariable::get()?" ? Or are you just confused about inheritance?

Comment: you can't define the functions in an interface. this is some acidic code.

Comment: Classes gets all from base, and put in object.Maybe i dont need interface, but i need solution maybe with abscract class. That has function, and then in another class to call abscract class function just to define $base.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have such code in a class? It really doesn't make much sense, all you do is select something from a database without checking whether there's a connection established and then you return an array, without checking whether you even got any results. Member functions that you wrote can be rewritten with PDO in a single line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for inheritance, rather than "interface." An interface says that an object that implements it will have certain methods, but must provide the body for them. In your case, you'll probably do best with an abstract class that has a concrete method of, we'll say, `Get()` and then an abstract method of `GetTable()`.

```
abstract class DatabaseObject {

    abstract protected function GetTable();

    public function Get() {
        $res=array();
        $r=mysql_query("select * from " . $this->GetTable());
        while($rw=mysql_fetch_row($r))
            $res[]=new $base($rw[0],$rw[1],$rw[2],$rw[3]);
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Then you can `extend` that with your classes. For example:

```
class menu extends DatabaseObject
{
    protected function GetTable ()
    {
        return 'menuitems';
    }
}
```

And now you can use `Get()` on that object to get the items out of the table.

The drawback with doing it this way is that you won't be able to use a static method -- you'll have to create an instance of your class.

Comment: Txanks, i this is what i need, because now i have full dinamic, i will have a lot of classes that will gather from different table in base. Thats why i asked about this interface, maybe it can be done to make interface that will do with base?

Comment: didn't you mean  `class menu EXTENDS DatabaseObject`?

Comment: @d_inevitable Oops! Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a common base class:

```
class Base {
   static $table=null;

   public static function GetItems ()
   {
      $table = static::$table;
      //...
   }
}

class Menu extends Base {
   static $table="menu";
   //...
}
```